# Jcomponent properties with double quote

Tags: java, jcomponent, swingx

i have a question related to this code

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
        String property = propertyChangeEvent.getPropertyName();
        if ("background".equals(property)) {
          button2.setBackground((Color)propertyChangeEvent.getNewValue());
```

Can you explain to me for this part of the code, "background".equals(property)? Why does it use the double quote for the background?

Answer (score 0):

"background" is a string - it's testing to see if the value of `property` is equal to the string "background".

Comment: What about  this one ?  UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.BLACK);
UIManager.put("Button.foreground", Color.RED);v

Comment: I don't know this framework at all, but it looks like it's setting colors to background and foregrounds, just guessing from the variable and method names.

Comment: Sorry if i am asking again, why does it use double quote, "Button.background" ?

Comment: Presumably, it's a string. Beyond that, I couldn't say, you'll have to check the documentation for whatever object `UIManager` is. It's probably doing something like storing the value of `Color.BLACK` in a element called "Button.background", but making assumptions without knowing is dangerous.